# Explanation needed for a proof about the Four Lemma in Module theory.

Tags: proof-explanation, exact-sequence

The following is taken from $\textit{Module Theory An Approach to Linear Algebra}$ By: T.S.Blyth

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Theorem 3.9:}$  $\textbf{[The four lemma]}$  Suppose that the diagram of $R-$modules and $R-$morphisms:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} A & \xrightarrow{f} & B & \xrightarrow{g} & C   \xrightarrow{h} & D     \\
\big\downarrow\alpha &  & \big\downarrow\beta &  & \big\downarrow \gamma &  \big\downarrow \delta & \\
A' & \xrightarrow{f'}& B' & \xrightarrow{g'} & C'   \xrightarrow{h'} & D'\end{array}$$

is commutative and has exact rows.  Then we have

$(1)$ if $\alpha, \gamma$ are epimorphisms and $\delta$ is a monomorphism then $\beta$ is an epimorphism

$(2)$  If $\alpha$ is an epimorphism and $\beta, \delta$ are monomorphisms then $\gamma$ is a monomorphism

> $\textit{Proof.}$ $(1)$  Let $b'\in B'.$ Since $\gamma$ is surjective there exists $c\in C$ such that $g'(b')=\gamma(c).$ By the commutativeity of the right-hand square we then have $\delta[h(c)]=h'[\gamma(c)]=h'[g'(b')]=0,$ since $h'\circ g'=0.$  Thus:

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I have a quick question about the partial proof of the Theorem above.
The line

"$\delta[h(c)]=h'[\gamma(c)]=h'[g'(b')]=0$ since $h'\circ g'=0$".

What is the reason that we can conclude

"$\delta[h(c)]=h'[\gamma(c)]=h'[g'(b')]=0,$"?

Is it because

$(1)$ Commutativity of the square

$(2)$ Commutativity of the square and that $\delta$ is a epimorphism, and hence the string of equalities allow for the map $D\xrightarrow{\delta}D'$ to be extended to the zero morphism $D'\to 0$ in order to make it exact, so that $\delta\circ h=0$ and in turn $h'\circ g'=0?$

Thank you in advance

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150035/discussion-on-question-by-seth-explanation-needed-for-a-proof-about-the-four-lem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is too much back and forth in the comments.  The answer to the original question is commutativity of the right square and exactness at $C'$, but the question now seems to be what exactness means.

Given a sequence of abelian groups or $R$-modules (this can be more general):

$A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}C\space$ (this can be part of a longer sequence including an infinite one)

the sequence is *exact* at $B$ if $Im\space f = Ker\space g$.

$Im\space f \subseteq Ker\space g$ is equivalent to $g\circ f =0$.

$Ker\space g \subseteq Im \space f$ means that any element sent to $0$ by $g$ comes from some element in $A$ via $f$.

$A$ or $C$ being $0$ are special cases where $g$ is injective and $f$ is surjective, respectively.

That's it and the link to Wikipedia in the first comment includes this and more.

Comment: thank you for the clear write up.  I am sure your answer will help others studying exact sequences also.